# How to add Explorer to JTextArea or JTextPane in java?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

[image]When I click the `menuitem` it opens the explorer using:

`Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("c:\\"))`

But how can I add Explorer to the `JTextArea` or `JTextPane`?

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: How is that supposed to work for users of OS X and *nix?  It won't happen, BTW - Swing text areas and text panes were not meant to host 'native' components.  OF course, we can replicate some of the functionality of a file explorer in Swing.  See the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784) for code to start with.

Comment: is it possiable in windows? @AndrewThompson

Comment: i have one more doubt desktop explorer is possiable to add directly to jframe? @AndrewThompson

Comment: What do you mean "add Explorer to..."?  Do you want embedded it?  Or do you mean provide the user with a file chooser of some kind?  As it stands you question doesn't make sense...

Comment: when i click menuitem explorer embedded to jframe.@MadProgrammer

Comment: *"is it possiable in windows?"*  I really don't care either way.

Comment: @kumar Swing isn't well suited for this